# jQuery on 'load' fails when Analytics and Piwik are being blocked

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, matomo

As soon as both Piwik and Google Analytics are being blocked e.g. with a browser privacy extension, other custom javascripts fail to execute when the code is wrapped in the jQuery `$(window).on('load', {})` event.

We discovered that on our company's website by coincidence. Further debugging showed that the custom scripts work if only **one** tracker is blocked, but it doensn't matter which one.

The different cases:

1. Nothing is blocked, rendering is okay

[image: Nothing blocked, no errors]

2. Piwik is blocked, rendering is okay

[image: Piwik blocked, rendering is okay]

3. GA is blocked, rendering is okay

[image]

4. Piwik and GA are blocked, code in `$(window).on('load', {})` for calculating panel sizes does not get executed, rendering is not okay.

[image: Piwik and GA blocked, Rendering not okay]

This is the custom pseudo javascript code

```
(function($, viewport) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // gets executed
        console.log("hello");

        // does not get executed when both trackers are blocked
        $(window).on('load', function() {
            calculatePanelSizes();
        });

    });
})(jQuery, ResponsiveBootstrapToolkit);
```

Do you have any hints on this?

Comment: You can put a try-catch when you call your trackers.

Comment: @OrcusZ: You mean I should try-catch in the copy&pasted tracking-code-stuff in the HTML-code (like [this](https://developer.piwik.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide))? Even if it helps, it does not explain what happens here...

Comment: yes, I think piwik & google-analytrics use "use strict" keyword, so the javascript engine raise more exception & sometimes it block the generation of our JS code. If you not able to be sure that your code will be executed before the one from google or piwik do it with try-catch